# How to get android navigation editor to work with many screens

Tags: android, android-studio, android-architecture-navigation

So I have this situation where I can't seem to get android studio to show my navigation graph layout visualization. Navigation editor used to work normally when there were 10 or so screens, but as I kept adding screens I started to notice that my editor would stop working and I would have to **invalidate caches and restart** for it to work again. But as I added even more screens to the graph, I can no longer get it to work. And to make matters worse, if I accidentally open navigation.xml, all layout preview windows stop working which is getting really annoying. I tried allocating more memory for android studio, but that didn't seem to help. I have layout attributes on each fragment/dialog and I can see placeholders in preview, but it just won't render layouts.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** this happens in **AS3.5**. Things get worse with **AS3.6 preview** as no graph is rendered at all.

Screenshot of current graph:
[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue with about a third as many screens in my most complex nav graph, except not only do the previews not load, but Android Studio  becomes very slow or unresponsive and runs out of memory. I've set the Xmx heap size to the max (3072MB) and it keeps happening. When it gets the out of memory exception, it gives an option to change the heap settings, with Xmx prepopulated to 3072 and text next to it saying "current value: 1280", even multiple restarts after I changed the setting. This is getting very frustrating.

Comment: The memory situation does not improve after closing the navigation editor.
So after using it and closing it, we need to restart Android Studio to keep working at all.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest refactoring some smaller, logically related sections of that navigation graph out into [nested navigation graphs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs). You can use an `<include app:graph="@navigation/nested_graph" />` tag much like you can do with layouts.  I recommend trying to pull out smaller features wherever it makes sense in your code.

This doesn't fix the problem of Android Studio not being able to handle a graph of that size, but it should work around it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, the graph nodes are too dependant for this to be a viable solution.